# How to store to list in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am making kivy app, something like project manager. I've got problem, i'll try to describe it.

In my app you can create new "project" by pressing button, then open the project and create some task. I need to store "project" into list or dictioniares. I've been thinking about this problem whole week and I can't solve. Do you have any ideas? I include my py. file and my kv. file here.

If you have some improvments to my codes, come here with them.

My python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
import sys
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen, SlideTransition, RiseInTransition
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.checkbox import CheckBox
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Rectangle, Line
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
from kivy.uix.stencilview import StencilView
Window.size = (400, 650)
Window.clearcolor = (0,0,0,0)
kv = Builder.load_file('main.kv')
c = 0
class MS(Screen, Widget):
    def on_exit(self):
        sys.exit()
class SES(Screen):
    pass
class OPS(Screen, BoxLayout):
    themes = ["DARK","LIGHT"]
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OPS, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        label = Label(text="COLOR THEME:", size_hint=(.2,.1), pos_hint={"x":.25,"top":.9})
        self.add_widget(label)
        tgbt = ToggleButton(text="DARK", size_hint=(.2, .1), pos_hint={"x":.5,"top":.9},background_normal="",background_color =(0,0,0,0))
        self.add_widget(tgbt)
        tgbt2 = ToggleButton(text="LIGHT", size_hint=(.2, .1), pos_hint={"x": .7, "top": .9},background_normal="", background_color= (1,1,1,1))
        self.add_widget(tgbt2)

class PRS(Screen, BoxLayout):
    widgets1 = []
    l1x = .1
    l1top = .87
    txt1x = .4
    txt1top = .88
    ck1x = .64
    ck1top = .88
    chtop = 0.88
    deltop = 0.88
    projects = []
    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'task'
    def changer2(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'main'
    def new_pr(self, *args):
        txt1 = TextInput(multiline=False,size_hint=(0.3,0.05), pos_hint={'x':self.txt1x,"top":self.txt1top})
        self.add_widget(txt1)
        label1 = Label(text="YOUR PROJECT NAME:",size_hint=(0.2,0.04),pos_hint={"x":self.l1x,"top":self.l1top})
        self.add_widget(label1)
        check1 = CheckBox(active=False, size_hint=(0.2,0.05), pos_hint={"x":self.ck1x,"top":self.ck1top})
        self.add_widget(check1)
        print(self.projects)
        self.widgets1.append(check1)
        self.widgets1.append(label1)
        self.widgets1.append(txt1)
        self.l1top = self.l1top - .07
        self.txt1top = self.txt1top - .07
        self.ck1top = self.ck1top - .07
        spinner = Spinner(text="OPTIONS", values="DELETE",background_normal="",background_color =(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1))
        button = Button(text="OPEN",color=(200 / 255.0, 194 / 255.0, 136 / 255.0, 1), size_hint=(0.1,0.05), pos_hint={"x":0.77, "top":self.chtop})
        self.add_widget(button)
        self.widgets1.append(button)
        button2 = Button(text = "DELETE",color=(200 / 255.0, 194 / 255.0, 136 / 255.0, 1), size_hint=(0.13,0.05), pos_hint={"x":0.87,"top":self.deltop})
        self.add_widget(button2)
        self.widgets1.append(button2)
        self.chtop = self.chtop - 0.07
        self.deltop = self.deltop - 0.07
        button.bind(on_press= self.changer)
        button2.bind(on_release= self.remover)
    def remover(self, *args):
        for i in self.widgets1:
            self.remove_widget(i)
        self.l1top = .88
        self.deltop = .88
        self.chtop = .88
        self.ck1top = .88
        self.txt1top = .88
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PRS, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        bt1 = (Button(text="NEW PROJECT",pos_hint={"x":.0,"top":1},size_hint=(.5,.1)))
        self.add_widget(bt1)
        bt2 = (Button(text="BACK",pos_hint={"x":.5,"top":1},size_hint=(.5,.1)))
        self.add_widget(bt2)
        bt1.bind(on_release=self.new_pr)
        bt2.bind(on_release=self.changer2)



    def clear_screen(self):
        self.canvas.clear()
class TASKS(Screen, BoxLayout):
    task1 = []
    tinpx = 0.25
    tinptop = .83
    chkx = 0.76
    chktop = .84
    showed = False
    def note(self, *args):
        self.showed = True
        if self.showed == True:
            textinput = TextInput(multiline=True,size_hint=(.4,.5), pos_hint={"x":0.56,"top":self.chktop-0.1})
            self.add_widget(textinput)
        while self.showed == False:
            self.remove_widget(textinput)
            break
    def change(self, *args):
        self.showed = False

    def changer(self,*args):
        self.manager.current = 'project'
    def new_task(self, *args):
        txt1 = TextInput(multiline=False, size_hint=(.2,.04), pos_hint={"x":self.tinpx, "top":self.tinptop})
        self.add_widget(txt1)
        chck1 = CheckBox(active=False, size_hint = (.2, .05), pos_hint = {"x":self.chkx,"top":self.chktop})
        self.add_widget(chck1)
        notes = Button(text="NOTES", color=(200 / 255.0, 194 / 255.0, 136 / 255.0, 1), size_hint=(.2,.05), pos_hint={"x":0.56,"top":self.chktop})
        notes.bind(on_press=self.note)
        notes.bind(on_release=self.change)
        self.add_widget(notes)
        self.tinptop = self.tinptop - .07
        self.chktop = self.chktop - .07
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TASKS, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(Label(text="TASK NAME", size_hint=(.2,.04), pos_hint={"x":0.25,"top":.88}))
        self.add_widget(Label(text="COMPLETE", size_hint = (.2,.04), pos_hint={"x":0.75,"top":.88}))
        bt1 = Button(text="NEW TASK",color=(0,0,0),size_hint=(.5,.1), pos_hint = {"x":0, "top":1},background_normal="",background_color =(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1))
        self.add_widget(bt1)
        homebt = Button(text="BACK",color=(0,0,0),size_hint=(.5, .1), pos_hint={"x":0.5,"top":1},background_normal="",background_color =(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1))
        self.add_widget(homebt)
        homebt.bind(on_release=self.changer)
        bt1.bind(on_release=self.new_task)

class Help(Screen, Widget):
    pass



class MApp(App):
    title = "PROJECT MANAGER"
    def build(self):
        wid = PRS(size_hint=(None, None), size=Window.size)
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MS(name = "main"))
        sm.add_widget(SES(name = "second"))
        sm.add_widget(OPS(name = "options"))
        sm.add_widget(PRS(name="project"))
        sm.add_widget(TASKS(name="task"))
        sm.add_widget(Help(name="help"))
        return sm
if __name__ == "__main__":
    MApp().run()
```

My kv. file:

```
<MS>:
    GridLayout:
        cols:7
        GridLayout:
            cols:2
            Button:
                text : "NEW"
                color:0,0,0
                on_release:app.root.current="project"
                background_normal:""
                background_color:(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1)


            Button:
                text : "OPTIONS"
                color:0,0,0
                on_release:app.root.current="options"
                background_normal:""
                background_color:(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1)
            Button:
                text : "LOAD"
                color:0,0,0
                on_release:app.root.current="second"
                background_normal:""
                background_color:(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1)
            Button:
                text : "HELP"
                color:0,0,0
                on_release:app.root.current="help"
                background_normal:""
                background_color:(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1)
            Button:
                text : "Next"
                color:0,0,0
                on_release:app.root.current="second"
                background_normal:""
                background_color:(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1)
            Button:
                id:bt1
                text : "Exit"
                color:0,0,0
                background_normal:""
                background_color:(200/255.0, 194/255.0, 136/255.0,1)
                on_release:app.stop()

<SES>:
    name:"second"
    Button:
        text:"back"
        color:0,0,0
        on_release:
            app.root.current="main"
<OPS>:
    name:"options"
    BoxLayout:
        Button:
            size_hint:.5,.2
            pos_hint : {"x":.5,"top":.15}
            text: "HOME"
            color:0,0,0
            on_release:app.root.current="main"
<PRS>:
    name:"project"
<TASKS>:
    name:"task"

<Help>:
    name:"help"
    GridLayout:
        Label:
            text:"COMING SOON!!!"
            color:0,0,0
```

Thaks for help, time and effort.
Micheno

Comment: Post a minimal runnable example demonstrating exactly where you want to do something, but can't work out how to do it. From your question it's very unclear what problem you actually have.

Comment: Hi my problem is that when i create like 5 projects and then open some of them and i'll add tasks the tasks with be added to all project

Comment: Ask a specific code problem, with a minimal runnable example

Comment: In class PRS - in method new_pr I am adding widgets to screen.(only if button is pressed). So can I store this widgets  to list. Every time, the method is called I want to create new list with widgets?

Comment: Yes, you can store your widgets in a list. I don't know what issue you have doing so. Post a minimal example so that it is easy to understand - what you have posted is very long and complicated, and mostly unrelated to your question.

Comment: But it store into the same list every time, so then when I want to remove widget i remove everything.

Comment: Then write a simple example demonstrating this process, and we can help by explaining how to change that example to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example of my problem.

```
    from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
class Test(BoxLayout):
    x1 = 0.2
    top1 = 0.9
    widgets = []
    def adder(self, *args):
        lb1 = Label(text="HELLO WORLD", pos_hint={"x":self.x1,"top":self.top1})
        self.add_widget(lb1)
        self.x1 = self.x1 - 0.05
        self.top1 = self.top1 - 0.05
        self.widgets.append(lb1)
    def remover(self, *args):
        for i in self.widgets:
            self.remove_widget(i)
        self.x1=0.2
        self.top1 = 0.9
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        bt1 = Button(text="ADD", pos_hint={"x":.1,"top":1}, size_hint=(0.2,0.4))
        self.add_widget(bt1)
        removebt = Button(text = "REMOVE",pos_hint={"x":.4,"top":1}, size_hint=(0.2,0.4))
        self.add_widget(removebt)
        removebt.bind(on_release=self.remover)
        bt1.bind(on_release=self.adder)



class APP(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP().run()
```

If i want to delete only one label it will delete all. Just try to copy and run it

Comment: Which Label do you want to delete?

Comment: Last i added, but this is only example for problem with my app which code is on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the last `Label` in the list:

```
def remover(self, *args):
    if len(self.widgets) > 0:
        self.remove_widget(self.widgets.pop(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

OK i could delete last that's improvement, but my problem is like this. What if I with button "ADD" I add text and button to remove the text and the button itself. Here is my new example with yours improvment.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (400, 650)
class Test(BoxLayout):
    x1 = 0.1
    top1 = 0.9
    widgets = []
    def adder(self, *args):
        lb1 = Label(text="HELLO WORLD", pos_hint={"x":self.x1,"top":self.top1})
        self.add_widget(lb1)
        removebt = Button(text = "REMOVE",pos_hint={"x":self.x1-0.1,"top":self.top1}, size_hint=(0.5,0.1))
        self.add_widget(removebt)
        self.widgets.append(removebt)
        removebt.bind(on_release=self.remover)
        self.widgets.append(lb1)
        self.top1 = self.top1 - 0.05
    def remover(self, *args):
        if len(self.widgets) > 0:
            self.remove_widget(self.widgets.pop(-1))
        self.x1=0.2
        self.top1 = 0.9
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        bt1 = Button(text="ADD", pos_hint={"x":.1,"top":1}, size_hint=(1,0.4))
        self.add_widget(bt1)
        bt1.bind(on_release=self.adder)



class APP(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    APP().run()
```