# How delete by button in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I have a problem which i nearly describe here: [How to store to list in kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65969334/how-to-store-to-list-in-kivy/65971806#65971806)
But i think nobody is reacting to it, so I give better describction here.
I want to add by button label and button to delete label and button itself. But how can i do it.
My code:
Just copy my code and try it it will delete every label and button you just add.

```
  from kivy.app import App
    from kivy.uix.label import Label
    from kivy.uix.button import Button
    from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
    class Test(BoxLayout):
        x1 = 0.2
        top1 = 0.9
        widgets = []
        def adder(self, *args):
            lb1 = Label(text="HELLO WORLD", pos_hint={"x":self.x1,"top":self.top1})
            self.add_widget(lb1)
            self.x1 = self.x1 - 0.05
            self.top1 = self.top1 - 0.05
            self.widgets.append(lb1)
        def remover(self, *args):
            for i in self.widgets:
                self.remove_widget(i)
            self.x1=0.2
            self.top1 = 0.9
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
            bt1 = Button(text="ADD", pos_hint={"x":.1,"top":1}, size_hint=(0.2,0.4))
            self.add_widget(bt1)
            removebt = Button(text = "REMOVE",pos_hint={"x":.4,"top":1}, size_hint=(0.2,0.4))
            self.add_widget(removebt)
            removebt.bind(on_release=self.remover)
            bt1.bind(on_release=self.adder)
    
    
    
    class APP(App):
        def build(self):
            return Test()
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        APP().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally understand what you want to do. The trick is to use a `Dictionary` instead of a list, to associate the `Label` with the `Button`. Here is a modified version of your `Test` class:

```
class Test(BoxLayout):
    x1 = 0.1
    top1 = 0.9
    widgets = {}  # widgets is a dictionary
    def adder(self, *args):
        lb1 = Label(text="HELLO WORLD", pos_hint={"x":self.x1,"top":self.top1})
        self.add_widget(lb1)
        removebt = Button(text = "REMOVE",pos_hint={"x":self.x1-0.1,"top":self.top1}, size_hint=(0.5,0.1))
        self.add_widget(removebt)
        removebt.bind(on_release=self.remover)
        self.widgets[removebt] = lb1  # Add Label to the dictionary
        self.top1 = self.top1 - 0.05
    def remover(self, button):
        lbl = self.widgets[button]  # get the Label that goes with the button
        self.remove_widget(lbl)  # remove the Label
        self.remove_widget(button)  # remove the Button
        self.x1=0.2
        self.top1 = 0.9
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        bt1 = Button(text="ADD", pos_hint={"x":.1,"top":1}, size_hint=(1,0.4))
        self.add_widget(bt1)
        bt1.bind(on_release=self.adder)
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. But what if I want to add more things into the dict. How to do it?

Comment: You can always put a list in the dictionary as the value, then just add more things to that list.